Force new iTerm tabs in existing window
How can I force to open new tabs in existing window?
Use case: I use launchbar to search for folders to open these in iTerm2 via shortcut CMD + T.
Observed behaviour: the folder opens in a completely new window instead of the existing window. New windows also actually look weird because it is missing close, minimize and maximize button.
Left side: normal existing window; right side: weird looking new window

